# How to filter data in Pandas by custom date?

Tags: python, pandas

There are some columns in Pandas dataframe:

```
name age mm yy
         01 23
```

How to filter rows where mmyy < current date using custom function (apply)?

mm and yy is as `8 non-null      object`

I tried this way:

```
from datetime import datetime

# mm = datetime.strptime(mm, "%m").strftime("%m")
# mm = datetime.strptime(mm, "%b").strftime("%m")  #str

mm = '06'
yy = '22'

cdd, cmm, cyy = datetime.today().strftime("%d %m %Y").split()
yy = datetime.strptime(yy, '%y').strftime("%Y")
mm = datetime.strptime(mm, "%m").strftime("%m")
 
dt = datetime(year=int(yy), month=int(mm), day=1)
present = datetime.now()
print(dt <present)
```

So, how to wrap this into custom function and apply in filter Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks, assuming the `mm` and `yy` columns contain strings:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Alice', 'Bob'], 'age':[20, 30], 'mm':['01', '04'], 'yy':['23', '22']})
print(df)

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.today().date()
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(f"{x.yy}/{x.mm}/01", "%y/%m/%d").date() < now, axis=1)]
print(df)
```

Input

```
    name  age  mm  yy
0  Alice   20  01  23
1    Bob   30  04  22
```

Output

```
  name  age  mm  yy
1  Bob   30  04  22
```

**UPDATE**: Based on OP's question in comments, this is how to do it if month is an abbreviated name like `Jan` for January (full docs on format codes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Alice', 'Bob'], 'age':[20,30], 'mm':['Jan','Apr'], 'yy':['23','22']})
print(df)

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.today().date()
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(f"{x.yy}/{x.mm}/01", "%y/%b/%d").date() < now, axis=1)]
print(df)
```

Input

```
    name  age   mm  yy
0  Alice   20  Jan  23
1    Bob   30  Apr  22
```

Output

```
  name  age   mm  yy
1  Bob   30  Apr  22
```

**UPDATE #2**: Here's a way to make this work for heterogeneous `mm` values (could be like '01', could be like 'Jan' for January):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Dexter'], 'age':[20,30,40,50], 'mm':['Jan','Apr', '02', '03'], 'yy':['23','22','22','23']})
print(df)

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.today().date()
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(f"{x.yy}/{x.mm}/01", "%y/%b/%d" if str.isalpha(x.mm) else "%y/%m/%d").date() < now, axis=1)]
print(df)
```

Input

```
     name  age   mm  yy
0   Alice   20  Jan  23
1     Bob   30  Apr  22
2   Carol   40   02  22
3  Dexter   50   03  23
```

Output

```
    name  age   mm  yy
1    Bob   30  Apr  22
2  Carol   40   02  22
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was close. Could you explain how to be if month is short name like "Jan"

Comment: Sure, see example in my updated answer.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as "accepted" if this answered your question.

Comment: So, does it work with two month formats: short name and short number?

Comment: `time data '23/03/01' does not match format '%y/%b/%d'`

Comment: I  got the problem if to use month as number 01 I have to apply `%m` if as short name `Jan` it should be %b.

Could I combine this into function and choose this automatically?

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically use `%m` if `mm` is numeric and use `%b` if it contains letters?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: OK, check UPDATE #2 in my answer. If you have any more follow-ups, please ask a new question, as that is the usual protocol (feel free to link it in the comments here and I'll take a look).